# Как извлечь значения из словаря? (если промежуточный ключ может меняться -- неизвестен заранее)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
thsU= {
    'success': 0, 
    'return': {
        '0000000000': {
            'pair': '', 'type': '', 'amount': 0.0, 'rate': 0.0, 'timestamp_created': 0000000, 'status': 0
        }
    }
}
```

нужно `'type'` и `'rate'`на месте `'0000000000'` может быть любой другой ключ, он динамичен.

Comment: По ключам не пробовали?

Comment: Alban пробовал вот так :thsR['return']['type']   ошибка нет такого ключа,мне нужно как то обойти  вот это значение  '0000000'

Comment: `thsR['return']['0000000000']['type']`

Comment: Alban было бы так просто то я бы сделал так,дело в том что значение '000000' меняется например может так '18764536' но числа с ними я разобрался а дальше ни чего не могу вытянуть

Comment: В словаре `return` всегда только один ключ который меняется?

Comment: да только вот этот с нулями ну и конечно значения ключей

Comment: Я имею ввиду в словаре `return` всегда только 1 ключ у которого значение это словарь? Или там может быть больше ключей?

Comment: Alban да ведь вот так:{'success': 0, 'return':{'0000000000': {'pair': '0.0','type':'0.0,'amount': 0.0 }}}

Comment: Alban получается словарь в словаре что ли...

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы выполнить: `some_dict['return'][*]['rate']`, где `*` соответствует *одному* (неизвестному) ключу:

```
assert len(some_dict['return']) == 1

[nested_dict] = some_dict['return'].values()
print(nested_dict['rate'])  # -> 0.0
```

Если больше одного ключа в промежуточном словаре может быть, тогда не ясно какое значение вы хотите изъять (словари неупорядочены в Питоне). Если любое значение подойдёт:

```
nested_dict = next(iter(some_dict['return'].values()))
print(nested_dict['rate'])  # -> 0.0
```

Comment: А что если так: `[nested_dict, *_] = some_dict['return'].values()`?

Comment: @NickVolynkin: если нет явных оснований, то не стоит O(1) операцию в O(n) превращать (по той же причине и `list(x)[0]` менее желателен).

Comment: А `next(iter(...))` выполняется за O(1), верно понимаю?

Comment: @NickVolynkin да: создать итератор, получить элемент

Comment: jfs,  Nick Volynkin спасибо мы уже разобрались,

Comment: @владимиржалеев пожалуйста, почитайте комментарий выше про O(1) и O(n). Пока что вы разобрались в не самом лучшем способе.

Comment: @владимиржалеев на Stack Overflow закрывают только те вопросы, которые не подходят для сайта (за некоторым исключением типа дубликатов, чтобы ориентирами служили). *Подходящие вопросы никогда не закрыты:* новый полезный ответ и через 10 лет могут опубликовать. Stack Overflow в основном существует, чтобы люди из поисковиков находили ответы, когда оригинальный автор вопросе может уже и позабыть что он его задал (я иногда свои ответы читаю, так как могу что-то забыть).

Answer (score 1):

```
In [5]: dictionary = {
   ...:     'success': 0,
   ...:     'return': {
   ...:         '0000000000': {
   ...:             'pair': '', 'type': '', 'amount': 0.0, 'rate': 0.0, 'timestamp_created': 0000000, 'status
   ...: ': 0
   ...:         }
   ...:     }
   ...: }

In [6]: dictionary['return'][list(dictionary['return'].keys())[0]]['rate']
Out[6]: 0.0
```

Comment: Alban вот ответ {'success': 1, 'return': {'6002491': {'pair': 'usd_rur', 'type': 'buy', 'amount': 6.1142887, 'rate': 57.0, 'timestamp_created': 1505924062, 'status': 0}}}
так сделал  thsR['return'][list(thsR['return'].keys())[0]]['rate'] ну и print(thsR) вот

Comment: @владимиржалеев но... Вы же не изменили изначальный словарь, зачем вы просто принтите его? https://repl.it/LXEi/0

Comment: Alban как не изменил? он же перезаписываемый

Comment: Ну вот же я Вам дал ссылку на пример

Comment: Alban вот with open ('thsR.txt', 'w+')as outfile:
                         json.dump(res.json(), outfile)

Comment: Alban но мне больше второй вариант понравился,мне кажется он проще

Comment: @владимиржалеев там практически тоже самое, но разбито для читабельности.

Answer (score 1):

```
vals = list(thsU['return'].values())
print(vals)
print(vals[0]['rate'])
```

Comment: Так даже лучше будет :)

Comment: Alban да спасибо,этот вариант подошел,а первый нет

Comment: @владимиржалеев что не так с первым?

Comment: Alban полностью все значения т ключи выводит

Comment: @владимиржалеев не понял.. можно пример?

Comment: если ровно один ключ ожидается, то можно использовать `[value] = d.values()`, вместо `value = list(d.values())[0]`